# hadoop parameters between jobs

Tags: java, hadoop, parameters, configuration, jobs

I have two jobs.
The first jobs map/reduce obtain two values only : 
          context.write(one,two).
But in the second jobs map/reduce I need a file and the two values.

I try put the result for the first job in context

In the reducer

```
 @Override
     protected void cleanup(Context context)
       throws IOException, InterruptedException {
          Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
          conf.setFloat("one",valorOne);
          conf.setFloat("two",valorTwo);
    }
```

And obtain this in the mapper of second job:

```
@Override
      protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException,
        InterruptedException {
         Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
          one=conf.getFloat("one",0f);
          two=conf.getFloat("two",0f);

      }
```

But the values are empty.

In the run

```
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
 Job job = Job.getInstance(getConf(), "1job");
        job.setJarByClass(job.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(ValoresWritable.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(ValoresWritable.class);

        job.setMapperClass(Job1Map.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(Job1Reducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Job1Reducer.class);         

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(input));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(output));

        job.waitForCompletion(true);


        Job job2 =  Job.getInstance(getConf(), "job2");
        job2.setJarByClass(job.class);

        job2.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job2.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        job2.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job2.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job2.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job2.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job2.setMapperClass(Job2Map.class);
        job2.setReducerClass(Job2Reduce.class);
```

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks